# Handle orientation when showing a view

Tags: iphone, uiview, orientation-changes

I have a few changes that get made to a UIView when the orientation changes. This works fine. The problem arises when adding the view after the phones orientation is already switched. This causes none of the rotate methods to be called and therefor does not give me the opportunity to make changes.

What would be the correct way of handling this, probably in ViewDidLoad? Would I be able to detect the current orientation at that point?

Bare in mind that its a few minor changes that I would need to make, so I dont want to load a different nib or anything like that

Thanks you very much :)

EDIT* just to clear things up: As I mentioned, the view is not even instantiated yet when the device orientation changes. The orientation changes to landscape -> the user clicks a button that shows another view -> this new view gets created and shown, but its default positioning is for portrait orientation -> when the view is shown, the elements I rearrange in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method are in the wrong position.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I put the animations that occur when the user rotates the device (manipulating the frames of views mostly) in the willAnimateToInterfaceOrientation method. In it's skeleton form it would look like this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //NSLog(@"willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: %d", toInterfaceOrientation);

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
    {
        // portrait
    }
    else
    {
        // landscape
    }
}
```

EDIT: In situations where I need to remember the device rotation for future use, I set up an ivar in my view controller class called currentOrientation (type int), and then do this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    //NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: %d", toInterfaceOrientation);

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        currentOrientation = toInterfaceOrientation;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then while running the methods in the view controller, I know which orientation the device is in.

Comment: As I mentioned, the view is not even instantiated yet when the device orientation changes. The orientation changes to landscape -> the user clicks a button that shows another view -> this new view gets created and shown, but its default positioning is for portrait orientation -> when the view is shown, the elements I rearrange in the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method are in the wrong position.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. I have the portrait defaults in the viewDidLoad, and both the landscape and portrait frames being set in the willAnimateRotationtoInterfaceOrientation method, but if the screen is loaded directly to landscape, that method never gets called.